# Yii2 save method doesn't save and doesn't throw an error

Tags: yii2

On my test server, which uses MS SQL, I call $this->save() from the model. In the debug log I see the resulting command:

UPDATE [Accounts] SET [ACCT_CLIENT_OFFICE]='DEMO', [ACCT_WORK_OFFICE]='DEMO', [ACCT_CLIENT2]='04', [ACCT_SUB_TYPE_ACCT1]='', [ACCT_SUB_TYPE_ACCT2]='', [ACCT_SUB_TYPE_ACCT3]='', [ACCT_SUB_TYPE_ACCT4]='', [ACCT_CLIENT_ACCT]='DEBTOR', [ACCT_LAST_NAME]='DILLLLLL', [ACCT_FIRST_NAME]='BEFFFFFFFF', [ACCT_COMPANY_NAME]='', [ACCT_AD1]='24 LADDRESS1', [ACCT_AD2]='', [ACCT_AD3]='', [ACCT_CITY]='MOCCCCCCCCI', [ACCT_ZIP6]='', [ACCT_COUNTRY]='', [ACCT_CURRENCY]='', [ACCT_LANGUAGE]='', [ACCT_EMAIL]='', [ACCT_WARNING]='', [ACCT_SERIES_NAME]='', [ACCT_LAST_LETTER]='LTR2', [ACCT_NEXT_ACTION]='', [ACCT_NEXT_ACTION_DTE]=0, [ACCT_CUR_AGNT_HIS]='', [ACCT_SPECIAL_TRACKING]='', [ACCT_STATUS]='RECALL', [ACCT_PRIOR_STATUS_DTE]='20220304', [ACCT_ACTIVE]='N', [ACCT_LSTCUR_SRVID]='', [ACCT_BFR_HOST_PORTFOLIO]='', [ACCT_DAY_STATUS_UPD]='RECALL', [ACCT_DAY_LETTER_REQ]='', [ACCT_DAY_SERIES_REQ]='', [ACCT_DAY_SEND_TO]='', [ACCT_CBR_LAST_SPCOMM]='', [ACCT_CBR_CCC]='', [ACCT_SOR_SYSTEM]='', [ACCT_CN_MISC_ID_X]='', [ACCT_ORIGINATOR_ID]='', [ACCT_ORIG_ACCT]='512350767', [ACCT_PURCHASE_FROM]='', [ACCT_SOLD_TO]='' WHERE [ACCT_ID]='103050843'

$this->save() returns true and the log shows no indication of any errors. I then refresh the record from the database and the columns have NOT been updated.

If I copy that statement to TablePlus and run it, it updates the database with no complaints.

When I run the app on my local machine which uses MySQL, works perfectly.

I am stumped.

Comment: Maybe there is an open transaction and you never commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

The table has parent / child records. There were two triggers that where updating the child records when the parent changed. Once I consolidated the two triggers into a single trigger, I was back in business.